# How does the Kendo UI cascading DropdownList works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, cascadingdropdown

Can Anyone explain to me the structures of this codes?

For an instance `.Name("products")` is the `DropDownList` name, I would like to know for what are those (what do you call this (`Name`, `OptionLabel`, etc.)) because it really confuse me. I'm stuck in creating a cascading `DropDownList`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("products")
      .OptionLabel("Select product...")
      .DataTextField("ProductName")
      .DataValueField("ProductID")
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("Type", "ComboBox")
                  .Data("filterProducts");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .Enable(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .CascadeFrom("categories")
)
<script>
    function filterProducts() {
        return {
            categories: $("#categories").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

```
<p>
<label for="orders">Orders:</label>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("orders")
      .OptionLabel("Select order...")
      .DataTextField("ShipCity")
      .DataValueField("OrderID")
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("SubType", "ComboBox")
                  .Data("filterOrders");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .Enable(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .CascadeFrom("products")
)
<script>
    function filterOrders() {
        return {
            products: $("#filterOrders").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can see the full details on the documentation that is in the kendoUI website
[Here's the Link](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.Name("orders")`: This is the unique name to assign to the dropdown html element.

`.OptionLabel("Select order...")`: This is what the dropdown should display when no option is selected.

`.DataTextField("ShipCity")`: This is the property of the datasource that populates the dropdown options that should be displayed in the dropdown.

`.DataValueField("OrderID")`: This is the property of the bound datasource that populates the dropdown options that should be used as the value to bind to the underlying model of the view.

`read.Action("SubType", "ComboBox")`: This defines the Action and Controller that should be called to retrieve the collection that will populate the dropdown options

`.Data("filterOrders")`: this is used to assign parameters to the above `read.Action` method

`.ServerFiltering(true)`:

`.Enable(false)`: Whether or not the dropdown is enabled.

`.AutoBind(false)`: Whether or not the dropdown should immediately bind to its dropdown datasource (or wait for the cascade from dropdown to be assigned a value)

`.CascadeFrom("products")`: The other DropDownList to cascade from.  If `AutoBind` is false, then this dropdown will only bind to its options datasource once the other dropdown has been assigned a value by the user.

Comment: I had an issue where the list was not showing up on the second dropdownlist (Always empty even if the Controller action was triggered). The ".ServerFiltering(true);" made it work perfectly.

Comment: .Enable(true) and .Autobind(true) are not working as intended. I want a default list on page load and it is always disabled and not bound. Probably a bug in Kendo DropDownList?

Comment: I'm guessing at what you mean by "default list"...if you mean a list that must always have a certain list of options, irrespective of other dropdowns, then this dropdown must not be part of the cascading tree (leave its CascadeFrom blank/null)